# JUnit 5 AfterAllTests feature

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, junit5

Is there a way to execute "AfterAllTests" action within JUnit 5? E.g. close connection to db, close embedded kafka cluster, etc.

P.S. There is a way to do some preconditions before all tests with help of extension  like that:

```
public class BeforeAfterExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

private static boolean FLAG = Boolean.TRUE;
...

@Override
   public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
      log.info("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ BeforeAll setup ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
      if (FLAG) {
         // some code here
         FLAG = Boolean.FALSE;
      }
   }

@Override
   public void afterAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
      // ??
   }
```

But no way for "After" tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use below mentioned code.

```
@AfterAll


static void afterAllIAmCalled() {       


    System.out.println("---Inside after finishing all testsDownAll---");


}
```

Link for you: https://www.concretepage.com/testing/junit-5/junit-5-beforeall-and-afterall-example

Updating answer further based on your need of running after all sets. Define your tests in suite as shown below

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)   


@ Suite.SuiteClasses({  


  SuiteTest1.class,


  SuiteTest2.class,     


})      


public class JunitTest {    


        // This class remains empty, it is used only as a holder for the above annotations but as you need to perform action at the end of it do as mentioned below


    @AfterSuite

 Private void methodName(){



//my suite end action

}


}
```

Replied on mobile. Might not be symmetric answer but will solve your problem.

This should work for you.

Comment: No, this is "after class" solution. Not "after all tests". I have more than 1 test class.

Comment: If that is the case I will recoup I using suites. Define a suit above your test class eq. @SuiteClasses({Test1.class, Test2.class}) and then use @AfterSuite to plan your closing activities.

Comment: Well
1. This suite should be updated if new class is added (dont want to have such duty)
2. Suites - means that you have some groups of tests. While here will be only one group which is "all tests". That is not what suites expected to be used for, imo.
3. Overall, how is it possible that there is no "AfterAllTests" or smth out of the box? I'm pretty sure I'm not the first person trying to close db connection at the end of my tests.

Comment: Test suites do not go together with Jupiter running on native JUnit platform support.